# Using Altair on data aggregated from large datasets

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to histogram counts of a large (300,000 records) temporal data set. I am for now just trying to histogram by month which is only 6 data points, but doing this with either json or altair_data_server storage makes the page crash. Is this impossible to handle well with pure Altair? I could of course preprocess in pandas, but that ruins the wonderful declarative nature of altair.

If so is this a missing feature of altair or is it out of scope? I'm learning that vegalite stores the entire underlying data and applies the transformation at run time, but it seems like altair could (and maybe does) have a way to store only the relevant data for the chart.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(timestamp):T'),
    y='count()'
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Altair charts work by sending the entire dataset to your browser and processing it in the frontend; for this reason it does not work well for larger datasets, no matter how the dataset is served to the frontend.

In cases like yours, where you are aggregating the data before displaying it, it would in theory be possible to do that aggregation in the backend, and only send aggregated data to the frontend renderer. There are some projects that hope to make this more seamless, including [scalable Vega](https://github.com/vega/scalable-vega) and [altair-transform](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair-transform), but neither approach is very mature yet.

In the meantime, I'd suggest doing your aggregations in Pandas, and sending the aggregated data to Altair to plot.

Edit 2023-01-25: [VegaFusion](https://vegafusion.io) addresses this problem by automatically pre-aggregating the data on the server and is mature enough for production use. Version 1.0 is available under the same license as Altair.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and altair! Is there ongoing work on altair-transform? I'd be interested in contributing if I can. The world would be a more beautiful place with this!

Comment: The shell of the functionality is there - search for TODO in the repository to see the places that need work. The other more complicated piece is pushing aggregations out of encodings and into transforms.

Comment: FYI - I've added some functionality to altair_transform which should now support this use-case. See https://github.com/altair-viz/altair-transform#example-pre-aggregating-large-datasets

Comment: Great. Thanks for the FYI. I've forked it and am taking a look to understand the general workings and will see if I can implement any TODOs

Answer (score 2):

Try below :-

```
alt.data_transformers.enable('default', max_rows=None)
```

and then

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(timestamp):T'),
    y='count()'
)
```

you will get the chart but make sure to save all of your work if the browser will crash.

Comment: Please don't just set max_rows=None without considering the consequences. If the page crashes with the ``json`` transformer or the data server transformer as mentioned in the question, then disabling max_rows will most certainly do the same, and in addition will add the entire serialized dataset to the cell output, which if saved will probably crash the browser on load whenever you try to use the notebook again.

Comment: @jakevdp the same I have mentioned in my answer as well! I don't know why you downvoted it. But there are times when you have 6000 rows and you don't get it done. In that case this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following works for me:

```html
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')
```